# How to configure multiple displays on Lenovo LEGION 5 Pro (Nvidia RTX 3050)

Tags: debian, xorg, nvidia, display, gpu

I have installed Debian 11 (bullseye) on a new Lenovo LEGION 5i Pro with Nvidia RTX 3050.

After installing the [Nvidia drivers](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Debian_11_.22Bullseye.22):

```bsh
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver firmware-misc-nonfree
```

I connected an external monitor using the HDMI port, but it was not recognized, it does not show up in the **Displays** settings.

I tried searching about the issue and I found somewhere someone fixing a similar problem with `xrandr`.

```bsh
~$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x4a cap: 0xf, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 7 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x2af cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 6 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-G0
```

This command fixed the problem, but honestly I don't know what it does:

```bsh
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0
```

But the problem is that the changes did not persist after reboot and I had a lot of lagging and `Xorg` was using about 30-40% CPU as shown using `top`. So I have uninstalled the drivers and started all over again.

Next I tried creating an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file using `nvidia-xconfig`, which created a file with these contents:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 460.32.03

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

The good thing is that the external monitor was recognized and I started using it and it was showing in the Displays settings, but I couldn't use the built-in display, and if I try to use the laptop without the external display I get a blank screen and I had to delete the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file and reboot to be able to use the built-in display.

How can I configure my system to be able to use both the built-in and the external display?

**Update**:

```
$ nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info
Number of GPUs: 1

GPU #0:
  Name      : GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop GPU
  UUID      : GPU-5f21a5b3-2add-7b3d-aa6b-1cfe5dd7085e
  PCI BusID : PCI:1:0:0

  Number of Display Devices: 1

  Display Device 0 (TV-4):
      EDID Name             : LG Electronics 24MP56
      Minimum HorizSync     : 30.000 kHz
      Maximum HorizSync     : 83.000 kHz
      Minimum VertRefresh   : 56 Hz
      Maximum VertRefresh   : 61 Hz
      Maximum PixelClock    : 150.000 MHz
      Maximum Width         : 1920 pixels
      Maximum Height        : 1080 pixels
      Preferred Width       : 1920 pixels
      Preferred Height      : 1080 pixels
      Preferred VertRefresh : 60 Hz
      Physical Width        : 510 mm
      Physical Height       : 290 mm
```

Listing the monitors using `xrandr`:

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 1
 0: +*eDP-1 1920/345x1200/215+0+0  eDP-1
```

After using this command `xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0` I get this output:

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 2
 0: +*eDP-1 2560/345x1600/215+0+0  eDP-1
 1: +HDMI-1-0 1920/510x1080/290+2560+0  HDMI-1-0
```

But the problem is high CPU usage by the `Xorg` process (30-40%).

Comment: Can you post the output of `nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info` if available?

Comment: @Natolio I have added the output, The LG device displayed is my external monitor, I don't know why it doesn't show my built in monitor as a display device, is this normal?

Comment: I do not have much experience in dealing with notebooks + external displays. Just in desktop displays connected directly to NVidia graphics cards. But this certainly makes it seem like the nvidia drivers are not recognizing your built in monitor as connected to the graphics card. My theory is that the notebook is designed to switch the built in monitor between the integrated graphics on the CPU and dedicated graphics card under different work loads for improved battery performance. I'm not sure how to test that, but are there any power profiles? If so could you set to high performance?

Comment: @Natolio thank you for the hint, I had an option **Graphic Device** in the BIOS with 2 modes, it was set to **Dynamic Graphics**, I changed it to **Discrete Graphic**  mode and I was able to use both displays, this mode uses the dedicated GPU only, please post an answer so I can accept it.
Thank you.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notebooks with separate dedicated and integrated graphics cards will try to balance which is used to improve battery life. Check `nvidia-settings` and bios settings to see if there is an option to specify which you would like to use.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix my problem temporarily by setting the **Graphic Device** mode to **Discrete Graphic** instead of **Dynamic Graphics** in the BIOS, then I was able to use both displays (built-in and external) at the same time without any high CPU usage from `Xorg` and without any extra configuration.
This method uses the dedicated GPU only and not the dynamic mode.

I have found another solution that didn't have any high CPU usage by `Xorg` while using the **Dynamic Graphics** mode in the BIOS, so I was using both GPUs.

I have followed the instructions on Debian's wiki:
[Using NVIDIA GPU as the primary GPU](https://wiki.debian.org/NVIDIA%20Optimus#Using_NVIDIA_GPU_as_the_primary_GPU)

1. I had the Nvidia driver installed following these [instructions](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Debian_11_.22Bullseye.22):

```
# Add "contrib" and "non-free" components to /etc/apt/sources.list, example:
# deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main contrib non-free
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver firmware-misc-nonfree
```

2. I had already `x11-xserver-utils` installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install x11-xserver-utils
```

3. Create a config file at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with the following contents:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "<BusID for NVIDIA device here>" # e.g. PCI:1:0:0
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "<BusID for Intel device here>" # e.g. PCI:0:2:0
    #Option "AccelMethod" "none"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection
```

You can get the bus ID using the `lspci` command:

```
$ lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a60 (rev 01)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 25e2 (rev a1)
```

Use these IDs like this in the `xorg.conf` file:

- `00:02.0` -> `PCI:0:2:0`
- `00:02.0` -> `PCI:0:2:0`

4. Create a `~/.xsessionrc` file with the following contents:

```
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --auto
```

If you get any errors running the first command, get the right name using this command, it could be other than `NVIDIA-0`:

```
$ xrandr --listproviders
```

5. Make the `~/.xsessionrc` executable:

```
$ chmod +x ~/.xsessionrc
```

6. Reboot and then you should be able to use both monitors and configure them using the "Displays" settings page